# I have 100 methods to test using Java selenium Junit. How do i write the methods without using @test annotation

Tags: java, selenium, junit

It's not feasible for me to write `@Test` annotation for each and every method in Selenium. Suppose I have to write `@Test` for 1000 methods again then it will be very tedious. 
How can I avoid this?

Comment: Also if i have to group them in TestNG then i will face challenges as i need to update each @Test annotation

Comment: _Suppose I have to write @Test for 1000 methods again then it will be very tedious_ can you elaborate in detail how this will become tedious for you ?

Comment: _i need to update each `@Test` annotation_ this is one time activity that you need to add suitable group name in your all test method. Ideally this should happen at the time you create test method and implement your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JUnit's Annotation Type Test

The `@Test` annotation tells [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/) that the `public void` method to which it is attached can be run as a *test case*. To run the method, [*JUnit*](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) first constructs a fresh instance of the class then invokes the annotated method. Any exceptions thrown by the test will be reported by *JUnit* as a failure. If no exceptions are thrown, the test is assumed to have succeeded.

Example of a basic JUnit test:

```
public class Example {
   @Test 
   public void method() {
       org.junit.Assert.assertTrue( new ArrayList().isEmpty() );
   }
}
```

---

### Conclusion

So if you have to write 1000 tests for 1000 methods, ideally you have to annotate each method with `@Test` annotation.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium test cannot be run from Eclipse IDE as console remains empty using JUnit5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76443138/7429447)

Comment: Note that in JUnit5 `@Test` methods don't need to be public anymore; in fact "[i]t is generally recommended to omit the public modifier for test classes, test methods, and lifecycle methods" according to the [user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-classes-and-methods).