# Selenium test cannot be run from Eclipse IDE as console remains empty using JUnit5

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to run some webdriver selenium code from eclipse as JUnit. I right click on "run configurations" and I get the following pop up window:
[image]

The structure of my project looks like this in eclipse:
[image]

I added 2 external jars for Selenium and JUnit, namely, `selenium-server-4.10.0.jar` and `junit5-api-5.0.0-ALPHA.jar`. When I click on run, nothing happens and I just get this written in eclipse:
[image]

Even my test string "MOUNA CAMELIA" does not get printed in the console. Here is my full code:

```
package Test;

// Generated by Selenium IDE
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class MounaTest {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private Map<String, Object> vars;
  JavascriptExecutor js;
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  }
  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
  }

  
  public void test() {
        System.out.println("MOUNA CAMELIA");

    driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/recs");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1552, 840));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Pos\\(a\\):nth-child(4) > .C\\(\\$c-ds-icon-secondary\\) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
    }
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element, 0, 0).perform();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Pos\\(a\\):nth-child(4) > .C\\(\\$c-ds-icon-secondary\\) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Bgi\\(\\$g-ds-background-like\\)\\3A a .D\\(b\\)")).click();
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Bgi\\(\\$g-ds-background-like\\)\\3A a .D\\(b\\)"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
    }
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element, 0, 0).perform();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JUnit lifecycle call back annotations for JUnit 4 vs JUnit 5](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/junit-annotations-tutorial/) are as follows:

[image: JUnit lifecycle call back annotations]

So using ***junit5-api-5.0.0-ALPHA.jar*** you need to:

- Replace `@Before` with `@BeforeEach`
- Replace `@After` with `@AfterAll`
- Need to add the hook:

  ```
  @Test
  ```

right before your test as follows:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println("MOUNA CAMELIA");
    driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/recs");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1552, 840));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Pos\\(a\\):nth-child(4) > .C\\(\\$c-ds-icon-secondary\\) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [I have 100 methods to test using Java selenium Junit. How do i write the methods without using @test annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62210891/7429447)

---

### tl; dr

[***JUnit 5 Annotations With Examples***](https://devqa.io/junit-5-annotations/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the up to date code which is fixed:

```
package Test;

// Generated by Selenium IDE
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class MounaTest {
  private static WebDriver driver;
  private Map<String, Object> vars;
  JavascriptExecutor js;
  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  }
  @AfterAll
  public static void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("MOUNA CAMELIA");

    driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/recs");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1552, 840));
    driver.get("https://tinder.com/");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1552, 840));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Miw\\(120px\\) .l17p5q9z")).click();
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Miw\\(120px\\) .l17p5q9z"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
    }
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element, 0, 0).perform();
    }
    vars.put("window_handles", driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".My\\(12px\\):nth-child(2) .Mend\\(a\\):nth-child(2)")).click();
    vars.put("root", driver.getWindowHandle());
    driver.switchTo().window(vars.get("win1725").toString());
    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(vars.get("root").toString());
    
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Pos\\(a\\):nth-child(4) > .C\\(\\$c-ds-icon-secondary\\) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
    }
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element, 0, 0).perform();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Pos\\(a\\):nth-child(4) > .C\\(\\$c-ds-icon-secondary\\) path")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Bgi\\(\\$g-ds-background-like\\)\\3A a .D\\(b\\)")).click();
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Bgi\\(\\$g-ds-background-like\\)\\3A a .D\\(b\\)"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
    }
    {
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.moveToElement(element, 0, 0).perform();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Mx\\(a\\):nth-child(4) path")).click();
  }
}
```